# Why would DHCP fail so often on a domestic network?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Recently I've noticed that one of my domestic devices (smartphone, laptop, pc) may lose its connection to the internet while other devices are still connected. It happens every day now. After a search on the web the most common cause seems to be a DHCP-related issue, most probably on router side as multiple devices are impacted. The solution given on the web is always to assign fixed IP address for the connections to that router. Ok but why ?

Why would DHCP fail that often ? There are at most 5 devices connected simultaneously on my network.

**Edit**: after a month doing different tests, here is what I got (device is Samsung Galaxy S7):

- using a static IP didn't help (-> DHCP is not to blame)
- going airplane mode then reconnect didn't help
- reboot smartphone didn't help
- forget + re-add the WiFi network seems to work: since I re-added the network, weeks ago, there is no more disconnection issue.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your question. We'd need a lot more information to give a definitive answer to this since there are a lot of possible causes for this problem. Can you confirm that setting a device to a static IP makes the problem go away, and tell us more about your router and post how its DHCP is currently configured? Once you've got that information, [edit] your question to include it and you're more likely to get some good answers :)

Comment: following are some general suggestions for "No Internet Connection" please see if it's helpful to you:https://www.highspeedinternet.com/resources/no-internet-connection-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Thanks. I will run some more tests and come back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Many home routers provide an interface to list the current DHCP clients and lease expiration times. The period of the lease renewal is also usually configurable. If you see that your device that loses its connection to the internet still has a valid lease (unexpired) in the DHCP clients table, then that means you will have ruled out DHCP as the cause of the problem.
If, however, you see that the loss coincides with DHCP lease expiration, then bingo you have found the cause and will likely need to modify your DHCP settings to use a longer lease period.

If you don't have access to the administrator interface for the router you are connecting to (for instance, if it is not a manually created network but something managed by an internet service provider or similar entity) then my guess is that DHCP issues are very unlikely, as the ISP will choose settings that will be designed to "just work" for most customers. In this case, try other avenues of investigation, like - are you connecting to 5GHz or 2.4GHz channels? Are there multiple access points for the same network and when you move your device closer to one of them the connection is more stable, whereas when you get in range of the other node it drops? And so on...

Comment: The configuration GUI of my router seems to be designed by the ISP (logo & colors). I have no explicit access to DHCP info like lease time. However I can assign a static IP to a device (like 192.168.0.x instead of 8.8.8.8 as regularly proposed on the web for that purpose).
I only use 2.4GHz with "automatic" channel.
There is only one access point and the disconnection issues happen when the device is not moving, and is at close range with a strong signal.